# JSON response and converting it to a JSON object

Tags: json

I have a piece of sample code to request for data from a website and the response I get turns out to be gibberish.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class NetClientGet
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    try
    {

        URL url = new URL("http://fids.changiairport.com/webfids/fidsp/get_flightinfo_cache.php?d=0&type=pa&lang=en");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        System.out.println("the connection content type : " + conn.getContentType());

        // convert the input stream to JSON
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

How do I convert the InputStream to a readable JSON Object. Found a few questions but they already have the response and trying to parse.

Comment: Do you want conn.getOutputStream() instead ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem with your code is that the server is g'zipping the response data, which you aren't handling. You can easily verify this by retrieving the data via a browser and looking at the response headers:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Fri, 10 May 2013 16:03:45 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) PHP/5.3.6
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   **Content-Encoding: gzip**
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Content-Type: application/json

Thats why your output looks like 'gibberish'. To fix this, simply chain a `GZIPInputStream` on top of the URL connections output stream.

```
// convert the input stream to JSON
BufferedReader br;
if ("gzip".equalsIgnoreCase(conn.getContentEncoding())) {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (new GZIPInputStream(conn.getInputStream()))));
} else {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));
}
```

The second issue is that the data returned is actually in JSONP format (JSON wrapped in a callback function, something like `callback_function_name(JSON);`). You need to extract it before parsing:

```
// Retrieve data from server
String output = null;
final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(16384);
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(output);
}
conn.disconnect();

// Extract JSON from the JSONP envelope
String jsonp = buffer.toString();
String json = jsonp.substring(jsonp.indexOf("(") + 1,
        jsonp.lastIndexOf(")"));
System.out.println("Output from server");
System.out.println(json);
```

So thats it, now you have the desired data from the server. At this point you can use any standard JSON library to parse it. For example, using [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
final JSONElement element = new JSONParser().parse(json);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, did not know about the GZIP encoding. +100 if possible but I can only accept your answer. Thanks again